# How non-integer coordinates work in Processing when drawing shapes?

Tags: processing, p5.js, generative-art

I'm trying to draw a series of lines and shapes that connect to each-other. Because of some calculations that I'm doing the coordinates for the lines/shapes end up being non-integer numbers and in this case there's a gap between lines that end and start at the same non-integer coordinate.
For example for this code:

```java
  void setup() {
    noLoop();
    size(500, 500);
  }
  
  void draw() {
  stroke(1);
  strokeWeight(100);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
  line(0, 0, 0, 200.5);
  line(0, 200.5, 0, 401);
  }
```

I get this result (note the gap between the two lines):
[image: two lines next to each-other]
Tried this also in p5.js with the same result. How is this working? Should I just always round to integers after doing my math?

Comment: I think you're seeing the strokeCap().  Try moving strokeCap() down one line.

Comment: Having the strokeCap(SQUARE) before drawing anything should apply it to all the lines after that. In my example both lines have the square cap.  
I was mostly interested in what's the logic behind this behaviour with non-integer coordinates. If you just change 200.5 to 200 the gap is gone.

Comment: Demo has been revised to include more options after adding background() to draw().

Answer (score 0):

After adding a background() call to the draw() the problem now appears to be with the SQUARE strokeCap as I initially thought and not the noLoop().  REM out strokeCap(SQUARE) and it runs ok.  UN-REM it and the lines come back with or without noLoop(); PROJECT caps and no caps are still without lines, with or without noLoop().  I don't think the float values make a difference.  Note that I removed the decimal values for strokeCap(SQUARE) to rule this out as a possibility. I'm unable to tell you why the lines occur with strokeCap(SQUARE), but the only way that I see to get rid of the lines is to use the PROJECT option, no caps at all, or keep them, but overlap the ends by 1 point.  For whatever it's worth, Processing Reference states that all parameters for line() are floats.

```
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  background(209); // Added and it makes a difference
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(50);
  // NO cap
  line(60, 80, 180.3, 80);  
  line(180.3, 80, 280.8, 80);
  line(280.8, 80, 380.5, 80);
  // (SQUARE) cap
  strokeCap(SQUARE); // REM this out to get rid of lines
  line(60, 160, 160, 160);
  line(160, 160, 260, 160);
  line(260, 160, 360, 160);
  // (PROJECT) cap
  strokeCap(PROJECT);
  line(60, 260, 160.5, 260);
  line(160.5, 260, 260.5, 260);
  line(260.5, 260, 360.5, 260);
  // (SQUARE) cap with 1 point of overlap
  strokeCap(SQUARE); // No lines with overlap
  line(60, 360, 160.8, 360);
  line(159.8, 360, 260.3, 360);
  line(259.3, 360, 360.5, 360);
}
```

Comment: You're right, testing some more in Processing seems that the gap is present with integer values as well. I was working in p5.js and that's where I encountered the difference. Sorry, I should have tested better in Processing as well. Here's a p5.js sketch that demos this: https://editor.p5js.org/nickdima/sketches/CTXTyrNa6

Comment: And as a side note, in Processing, not calling strokeCap just uses the default value which is ROUNDED.

Comment: This is getting even weirder. It seems that on my MacBook Pro's screen the same sketch has no gaps between the lines. While on my external screen, which is a lower res, the gap is present (only for the non-integers). Probably it has something to do with subpixel rendering in the browser.

Comment: The MacBook Pro probably is a 'retina' which has twice the number of pixels if I recall correctly.  I've also posted in the Processing Forum to see if we can get more information about the source code over there.  I do know that an issue of using strokeCap(SQUARE) with a point has previously been raised, but to me that would almost be predictable given the small size of a point.

Comment: I just ran the above demo in the p5.js web editor and I don't see any lines (even with my magnifying glasses on).  So my new conclusion is that the problem is only seen with the desktop version.  I use the same monitor (4k) for both the Processing IDE and the p5.js web editor.  The renderers could be different: one uses macOS (java?) and the other uses a renderer from the web??  I would expect both to use openGL, but I think Mac quit supporting it; if so I'm not sure what it uses instead, unless Processing editor provides a copy.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you don't see the gap because you're testing on a 4K monitor. My external monitor has lower res and that's where I see the gap.

Comment: I do see the gap on my 4K monitor if I run the code in Processing editor but not if I run the code in p5.js web editor.  That's why I'm suspicious of the renderers on the respective systems.  There is a WEBGL for p5.js.  Not sure what renderer Processing uses on a Mac.

Comment: Found this thread on GitHub: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1516
The last comment talks about using a higher pixelDensity(), that seems to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241012/discussion-between-apodidae-and-nick-dima).